# how to set max_bin params in LightGBM

Tags: python, lightgbm

Following code throws error saying "Unexpected keyword arguemnt 'max_bin'". Later I found ['max_bin' is depreciated](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1100). So how can I pass max_bin using 'params'? Can anyone show me a piece of sample code?

```
lgb.Dataset(x_train, lable=y, max_bin=56)
```

> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py:648: LGBMDeprecationWarning: The max_bin parameter is deprecated and will
>   be removed in 2.0.12 version. Please use params to pass this
>   parameter.
>       'Please use params to pass this parameter.', LGBMDeprecationWarning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `params` mentioned in the error message refer to the [Parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/docs/Parameters.rst) that are passed to the `train()` function. If you use the sklearn classes of the python API, some of the parameters are also available as keyword arguments in the classifier's `__init__()` method.

**Example:**

```
import lightgbm as lgb
import numpy as np

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

iris = datasets.load_iris()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris.data,
                                                    iris.target,
                                                    test_size=0.2)
lgb_train = lgb.Dataset(X_train, y_train)

# here are the parameters you need
params = {
    'task': 'train',
    'boosting_type': 'gbdt',
    'objective': 'multiclass',
    'num_class': 3,
    'max_bin': 4  # <-- max_bin
}

gbm = lgb.train(params,
                lgb_train,
                num_boost_round=20)

y_pred = gbm.predict(X_test, num_iteration=gbm.best_iteration)
y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
print("Accuracy: ", accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

For a detailed example i recommend taking a look at the [python examples](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/d22de3c2ffd90c1484def2a69ef916c67be986aa/examples/python-guide/simple_example.py) that come with LGBM.

Answer (score 0):

Set `max_bin` in the `params` dictionary, then pass it to the `lgb.Dataset` constructor. Note that `max_bin` is specified as a Dataset parameter in the [official doc](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html).

```
import lightgbm as lgb

lgb.Dataset(x_train, label=y_train, params={"max_bin": 63})
```